# <error-page> web.xml is not working

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, exception

I am trying to learn the usage of tags  in JSP Servlets and getting stuck with an issue. I have provided the configuration in web.xml but the control is not going to the desired location. I took this sample code from a forum. Can someone please guide me where am I going wrong.

**MyExceptionServlet.java**

```
package com.journaldev.servlet.exception;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/MyExceptionServlet")
public class MyExceptionServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    throw new ServletException("GET method is not supported.");
    }

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>ServletExceptionHandling</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/AppExceptionHandler</location>
  </error-page>

  <error-page>
      <exception-type>javax.servlet.ServletException</exception-type>
      <location>/AppExceptionHandler</location>
  </error-page>
</web-app>
```

**AppExceptionHandler.java**

```
package com.journaldev.servlet.exception;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/AppExceptionHandler")
public class AppExceptionHandler extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException     {
    processError(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processError(request, response);
}

private void processError(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    // Analyze the servlet exception
    Throwable throwable = (Throwable) request
            .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
    Integer statusCode = (Integer) request
            .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
    String servletName = (String) request
            .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.servlet_name");
    if (servletName == null) {
        servletName = "Unknown";
    }
    String requestUri = (String) request
            .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.request_uri");
    if (requestUri == null) {
        requestUri = "Unknown";
    }

    // Set response content type
      response.setContentType("text/html");

      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      out.write("<html><head><title>Exception/Error Details</title></head><body>");
      if(statusCode != 500){
          out.write("<h3>Error Details</h3>");
          out.write("<strong>Status Code</strong>:"+statusCode+"<br>");
          out.write("<strong>Requested URI</strong>:"+requestUri);
      }else{
          out.write("<h3>Exception Details</h3>");
          out.write("<ul><li>Servlet Name:"+servletName+"</li>");
          out.write("<li>Exception Name:"+throwable.getClass().getName()+"</li>");
          out.write("<li>Requested URI:"+requestUri+"</li>");
          out.write("<li>Exception Message:"+throwable.getMessage()+"</li>");
          out.write("</ul>");
      }

      out.write("<br><br>");
      out.write("<a href=\"index.html\">Home Page</a>");
      out.write("</body></html>");
}
}
```

**Error Stack Trace**

```
Apr 23, 2014 11:30:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet   [com.journaldev.servlet.exception.MyExceptionServlet] in context with path [/ServletExceptionHandling] threw exception [GET method is not supported.] with root cause
javax.servlet.ServletException: GET method is not supported.
at com.journaldev.servlet.exception.MyExceptionServlet.doGet(MyExceptionServlet.java:15)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

By looking at the error stack trace its clear that the control is not going to the "/AppExceptionHandler" url as specified in the web.xml.

Snapshot of eclipse browser when trying to access the URL :

```
**http://localhost:8081/ServletExceptionHandling/MyExceptionServlet**
```

[image]

By going through various portals, I did the following analysis.
this problem can occur when using servlet version other than 3 but I checked the manifest file of the servlet-api.jar bundled within tomcat installation and its 
Specification-Title: Java API for Servlets
Specification-Version: 3.1

Some forums said, its the problem with IE, hence I checked in Mozialla, Eclipse browser. I feel that the error tags in web.xml are not being identified correctly. Else the URL would have got changed to something else. Even the stacktrace suggests that the redirect to AppExceptionHandler.java is not happening.

Some more information regarding versions

Eclipse Juno Service Release 2
Tomcat Version 8
JRE7
JDK1.7

**On request directory structure in the eclipse.**
[image]
Please help.

Regards Tarun

Comment: Could you list all files in deployed web(war) archive. I have created new project (in IntelliJ IDEA) with your sources and it works on Tomcat 8.0.3. Possibly your web.xml is missing or is in invalid directory.

Comment: Thanks for the attention Marek. Since I am working using eclipse, I am not building a war, Am just trying to run the servlet (MyExceptionServlet.java) in server. I am unable to post the snapshot of the directory structure in this reply , hence will update my original post with the snapshot.

Comment: Try to export war file in following way and check if web.xml is in WEB-INF directory: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftwcrewar.html

Answer (score 0):

Reload not supported on WAR deployed at path /foo

Currently, application reloading (to pick up changes to the classes or web.xml file) is not supported when a web application is deployed directly from a WAR file. It only works when the web application is deployed from an unpacked directory. If you are using a WAR file, you should undeploy and then deploy or deploy with the update parameter the application again to pick up your changes.